# How to get the position right

Tags: html, css

I want `menu` still on the top, but now when I mouseover one `menu`, others can't on the top

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

before：

[image]

after：

[image]

expected：

[image]

### my code

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.nav');
var lis = ul.children;
console.log(lis);
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'block';
  }
  lis[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border: 3px solid green; */
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(245, 108, 172);
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #ff8500;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li {
  border: 1px solid rgb(173, 236, 25);
}

.box ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 34px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f1b97c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class=nav>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `vertical-align` property.

Setting your `.nav > li` to have `vertical-align:top;` will resolve your issue without having to change much code.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.nav');
var lis = ul.children;
console.log(lis);
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'block';
  }
  lis[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border: 3px solid green; */
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(245, 108, 172);
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #ff8500;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li {
  border: 1px solid rgb(173, 236, 25);
}

.box ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 34px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f1b97c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class=nav>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex` for `.nav{...}`

NOTE:

> Removed `console.log()` in js since it looks like error.

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('.nav');
var lis = ul.children;

for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  lis[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'block';
  }
  lis[i].onmouseout = function() {
    this.children[1].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.nav>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(245, 108, 172);
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #ff8500;
}

.box {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li {
  border: 1px solid rgb(173, 236, 25);
}

.box ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 34px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #f1b97c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class=nav>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu</a>
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```